# Indexing across 3 columns

Tags: google-sheets, indexing

I am making a system to find if there are students who take certain subjects in different subject blocks. Here is an example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QQC68PAJeOavOVoGPmyruzIS4jMjOtnMl1siNqOJxQg/edit?usp=sharing)

For example, if I wanted to find students who have 'Drama' as subject 1, and 'Art' as subject 3, it would output the pupils 3 & 5. This would be the same if I asked if there were students any subject in Subjects blocks 1-3, science and language.

I have tried `=INDEX(A2:A7, MATCH(1, (B2:B7=B10)*(C2:C7=C10)*(D2:D7=D10)*(E2:E7=E10)*(F2:F7=F10), 0))` but it is not working.

Is it possible to help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=join(", ",filter(A2:A7,
             if(B10="",1,B10=B2:B7)*
             if(C10="",1,C10=C2:C7)*
             if(D10="",1,D10=D2:D7)*
             if(E10="",1,E10=E2:E7)*
             if(F10="",1,F10=F2:F7)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried to expand the data base and modify the locations, for some reason it is not working: =join(", ",filter(A2:A151,
             if(B184="",1,B184=B2:B151)*
             if(C184="",1,C184=C2:C151)*
             if(D184="",1,D184=D2:D151)*
             if(E184="",1,E184=E2:E151)*
             if(F184="",1,F184=F2:F151)))

Comment: It does not recognise A2:A151 as a range at all...

Comment: IF **no matches** are found by the formula, its bound to throw an error. Recreate the error scenario in your test sheet & I can check it out.

Comment: please look at sheet two

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/H8js2fe.png I tried the exact formula you pasted above and its working good to me.

Comment: that is really odd... how can i fix this...?

Comment: Just delete the error formula & paste it fresh again maybe!!

Comment: i've done that a few times already :(

Comment: Provide edit access to the sheet

Comment: how does one 'clear' a cell, is it just delete the contents within? i'm doing this with the actual sheet, its still weird

Comment: Just try the formula in a totally different cell & see if its the same error OR working good?!

Comment: it does not work still...

Comment: Sorry I have no idea then...

Comment: it is not recognising A2:A151 is a range